# How do I sample a certain number of rows in a database table from a python script?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table with a list of items. I created a randomly generated order list to create 500 orders with item range 1-5. I need to take the numbers in the orders list and randomly generate x amount of rows from the items table.

```
import random
import numpy

Orders = numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=500)

for o in Orders:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items limit 5")
    row = cursor.fetchmany(size = o)
    while row is not None:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchmany(size = o)
```

this is giving me an endless amount of empty lists.

EDIT:

```
for o in Orders:
    cursor.execute("select * from items order by rand() limit 5")
    row = cursor.fetchmany(size = o)
    print(row)
```

I just edited the code to the above. It is now working for the first number in the order list. How do I get it to loop through the entire order list?

Answer (score 1):

What is the intention of `size = o`? Also, is that a o instead of 0? The size arg will limit the number of rows returned.

From the MySQL docs:

> The number of rows returned can be specified using the size argument

Comment: I want it to run 500 times with the amount of rows fetched from the table equal to the randomly generated integer in order. Yes it is an o, not a 0.

Comment: Why not fetch the entire cursor once and then operate on the list of tupples instead?

Have you verified that there is data in the cursor?

Comment: Yes I have but I'm not sure how to do what you're suggesting. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I just edited what I currently have, please see above.

Comment: `Orders = numpy.random.randint(1,6,size=500)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items limit 5")  

row = cursor.fetchall()`

Then use a list comprehension to build a random list using your Order list.